# How to get a database backup without using runtime commands from Java

Tags: java, mysql, backup

I want to know how to get a mysql database backup without using runtime commands from Java code.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a MySQL backup need not have anything to do with Java.

Use the MySQL backup scripts.  Run them using a cron job if you wish.

Comment: can u post any backup script because i am not aware of backup scripts

Comment: my requirement is i should not use any mysqldump commands. so how can i do this.

Comment: Hi duffymo,if i use mysqldump i think i should have previlizes to ruu the dump command and if the mysql server is running in another machine they should open the remote connections we can't ask client to do all this things without doing this can u suggest any option.sorry for my english,thanks in advance